# How to increase vertical spacing in \begin{align}

Tags: align, vertical-spacing

I'd like to know how to increase the vertical spacing in `align`. The sample code is as follows:

```
\begin{align*}
    T(\varphi_3(y)\barwedge\theta(z)) & \,=\int_{0}^{t_{y}}\int_{0.5t}^{s_z}f(t,s)\,d\alpha(s)\,d\gamma(t)
    \\
    & \,=\, 10 \int_{0}^{t_{y}}(s_z-0.5t)\,d\gamma(t)
    \\
    & \,=\, t_y\left(4s_z-t_y\right)/4
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to increase the vertical spacing *locally*, you can use the  `spreadlines` environment from `mathtools`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{spreadlines}{2ex}
    \begin{align*}
        T\bigl(\varphi_3(y)\barwedge\theta(z)\bigr)
            & = \int_{0}^{t_{y}}\int_{0.5t}^{s_z}f(t,s)\,d\alpha(s)\,d\gamma(t) \\
            & = 10 \int_{0}^{t_{y}}(s_z-0.5t)\,d\gamma(t) \\
            & = t_y\left(4s_z-t_y\right)/4
    \end{align*}
    \end{spreadlines}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is `\setstretch` not working in this case?

Comment: @hermes; I have no real idea. Maybe  multined equations environments neutralize \settretch, but it's only a hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

You only need to add desired vertical space in square bracket after line termination (in code marked by `% <---`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    T\bigl(\varphi_3(y)\barwedge\theta(z)\bigr) 
        & = \int_{0}^{t_{y}}\int_{0.5t}^{s_z}f(t,s)\,d\alpha(s)\,d\gamma(t) \\[1ex] % <---
        & = 10 \int_{0}^{t_{y}}(s_z-0.5t)\,d\gamma(t)                       \\[1ex] % <---
        & = t_y\left(4s_z-t_y\right)/4
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

**Edite:** As pointed @ in his comment below (thank you!) another, global possibilities is  increase `\jot` distance, which control distances between equation lines) globally:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\addtolength{\jot}{1ex} % <--- increase space between equation lines

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    T\bigl(\varphi_3(y)\barwedge\theta(z)\bigr) 
        & = \int_{0}^{t_{y}}\int_{0.5t}^{s_z}f(t,s)\,d\alpha(s)\,d\gamma(t) \\
        & = 10 \int_{0}^{t_{y}}(s_z-0.5t)\,d\gamma(t)                       \\
        & = t_y\left(4s_z-t_y\right)/4
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Result is similar as before:

[image]

BTW, in both examples above I remove added spacing around `=` symbol.

Comment: If you don't want to manually set it for each row, you can use `\addtolength{\jot}{1em}` to add a constant amount to each break. There's also the spreadlines environment from the [mathtools](https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf) package.

Comment: @frabjous, of course. However OP is not clear, if this is needed just for showed equation or (s)he like to have global settings. I show just simplest local possibilities. To answer is now added this possibility .

Comment: @Zarko, your code involving `jot` seems to set extra spacing for every `align` block which I do not need. I only want to set a particular block of `align`

Comment: @hermes, yes. This is clearly stated in my answer-